# Are Symbiotic and Vampire Stars the same type of star or different?

Tags: star

Are Vampire Stars and Symbiotic Stars the same type of star or is there a difference?

Vampire Stars siphon off hydrogen from its neighbour.  According to https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~kenyon/ss/, Symbiotic Stars seem like the same description.

"In all systems, the hot component - a main sequence star, a white dwarf, or a neutron star - accretes material lost by the red giant." (Harvard)

SS Leporis has been described as Symbiotic Star and in some places as Vampire Stars.

Comment: Can you tell us where you've heard the term "vampire star" used before? As I understand it, "symbiotic binary" is a technical term; "vampire star" is almost certainly just something used in magazine articles.

Comment: Am pretty certain that I first time I heard it was watching episode 5... https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1832668/episodes?season=5 .  The term Vampire Star is used by a lot of places including E.S.O. https://www.eso.org/public/unitedkingdom/news/eso1148/  .  I'm trying work out if they're terms for the same thing.

Comment: AFAIK all those are roch-lobe overflow binaries, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the title of the [research paper](https://www.eso.org/public/archives/releases/sciencepapers/eso1148/eso1148.pdf) linked to in the ESO press release is "*An incisive look at the symbiotic star SS Leporis*", it is safe to conclude that they are the same type of star. My suspicion is that, since symbiotic stars transfer and accrete mass via either Roche-lobe overflow or stellar wind overflow, the term "vampire star" was coined as part of the press release as a "cute" way to imply that one star is "feeding" on another.